# Custom plugin settings: clicking "save changes" does not display success message

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin, options, settings-api

I don't entirely understanding how to save my [plugin's settings](http://prntscr.com/c9xf49) properly. When I click on the "*Save Changes*" button it saves data but it does not show any successful like message. Do I need to add an extra function or something else?

My form look like this:

```
function bdthemes_core_settings_page() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>BdThemes Settings</h1>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                settings_fields("section");
                do_settings_sections("plugin-options");      
                submit_button(); 
            ?>          
        </form>
    </div>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: Normally, using the Settings API as you have will cause a default "Settings Saved" message. The problem would be somewhere else in your mark-up, though you could also try writing an explicit custom message via the admin_notices hook.

Comment: @CKMacLeod If one creates a sub menu and posts to options.php from there, it skips the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue as you did, but I found how to fix it in this tutorial:

https://digwp.com/2016/05/wordpress-admin-notices/

Basically, I had my settings page outside of the Settings menu, so I had to explicitly add `settings_errors()` to my options page and they started working. :)

Hope that helps.